# "No git binary found" and "npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory" in docker container

Tags: node.js, git, docker, npm, circleci

This docker setup was working last week. Since then the only real changes have been some new dependencies and some minor code updates. It's what I use to deploy our app with CircleCI and nothing about this configuration has changed since last time I used it.

**`Docker` file**

```
FROM node:10-alpine as base

EXPOSE 3001

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY server/package.json server/package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./server/ ./

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "server:prod"]
```

I get a bunch of errors like this:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/node_modules/.staging/request-2b86f7e4/index.js'
```

And this error as well:

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/timsuchanek/codemirror-graphql.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
```

If I remove the `package-lock.json` file I stop getting this error `npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory`. But I still get `No git binary found in $PATH`.

NOTE: that if I run `npm install` outside the Docker container it works fine.

This is driving me mad is it's suddenly stopped working and we can't deploy any updates to our app. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: ---

I added the following to the docker file (based on the answer below) and it fixed the issue.

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache bash git openssh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker description of `node:alpine` image says:

> To minimize image size, it's uncommon for additional related tools (such as git or bash) to be included in Alpine-based images. Using this image as a base, add the things you need in your own Dockerfile (see the alpine image description for examples of how to install packages if you are unfamiliar).

See the [description](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)

Comment: Based on your comment here and this link (https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/586) I added git to the image. But I have no idea why this used to work and no longer does...

Comment: I suppose you initially used a full image (not alpine) and that's why everything worked. Or earlier you didn't use packages from github.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a ssh key to the container with right permission.

check this for reference https://medium.com/paperchain/fetching-private-github-repos-from-a-docker-container-273f25ec5a74